# Merge custom product attributes options in one

Tags: magento, attributes

I have many product custom attributes all have same type dropdown for **brand** like

```
brand_cosmetic
cos_acc_brand
face_brand
mobile_brand
```

They have lot of options. i want to make a new attribute name `product_brand` and want to merge all above attribute options in it is there any way in magento to do this programmatically. I have searched alot but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my below example I have deleted the

> brand_cosmetic,cos_acc_brand,face_brand,mobile_brand attributes and
>   created a new test_drop attribute

for all combine option.

Create a file test.php at root and pest this below code and run in browser.

```
<?php  
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$newArr = array();

//Possible brand_cosmetic value
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand_cosmetic'); //"color" is the attribute_code
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
    $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
    $newArr[$id] = $value;
}

//Possible cos_acc_brand value
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'cos_acc_brand'); //"color" is the attribute_code
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
    $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
    $newArr[$id] = $value;
}

//Possible face_brand value
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'face_brand'); //"color" is the attribute_code
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
    $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
    $newArr[$id] = $value;
}

//Possible mobile_brand value
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'mobile_brand'); //"color" is the attribute_code
$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
    $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
    $newArr[$id] = $value;
}

$newArr = array_filter($newArr);

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();                   

$opionsarr = array_values($newArr);
// Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'test_drop', [
    'type'       => 'int',
    'input'      => 'select',
    'label'      => 'Test Drop',
    'sort_order' => 1000,
    'required'   => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'visible_on_front'  => true,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'option'     => [
        'values' => $opionsarr
    ],

]);

// To delete the existing product attribute
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand_cosmetic');
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'cos_acc_brand');
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'face_brand');
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'mobile_brand');

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Comment: dude i asked like how to merge values not want to delete

Comment: I did the same programmatically as you did using import profile. If you don't want to delete the existing attributes than remove the removeAttribute lines from bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue its not the best way but it fixed my issue may be it helps someone as well so what i have done i made a **function** that is fetching all the options of brand attributes in my project

```
public function mergeAttributeOtionsAction(){
    $brands = array();
    $attSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_code','catalog_product')->getFirstItem(); // This is because the you adding the attribute to catalog_products entity ( there is different entities in magento ex : catalog_category, order,invoice... etc ) 
    $attSetCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->load($attSet->getId())->getAttributeSetCollection(); // this is the attribute sets associated with this entity 
  foreach ($attSetCollection as $a)
    {
        if(preg_match('/cosmetic/i', $a->getAttributeSetName())){
            $set = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($a->getId());
            $setId = $set->getId();
            $atrr_ = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($setId);
            foreach($atrr_ as $atrr){

                $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',$atrr['code']);
                if(preg_match('/brand/i', $attribute->getFrontendLabel())){
                    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
                    foreach ($options as $option){
                        if($option['label'] == 'Not Specified'){
                            continue;
                        }
                        $brands[] = $option['label'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump(implode(',', $brands));echo '</pre>';
    foreach ($brands as $brand){
        echo $brand; echo '<br>';
    }    

 }
```

the next step is to make an excel file in this format
[image]

than goto **admin > system > import/export > DataFlow - Advanced Profiles** Add new Profile enter name like "Import Product Attributes" and add this XML and save

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
<var name="type">file</var>
<var name="path">datafiles/import</var>
<var name="filename"><![CDATA[import_product_attributes.csv]]></var>
<var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
<var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[;]]></var>
<var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
<var name="fieldnames">true</var>
<var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
<var name="number_of_records">1</var>
<var name="adapter">importexportattributes/convert_adapter_product_attribute</var>
</action>
```

Now create a folder on magento root folder name datafiles inside this folder create another >import than place that XML file here that you have created above.

Now goto **admin > system > import/export > DataFlow - Advanced Profiles open "Import Product Attributes"** than click on **Run Profile** tab and click on **run profile** button. 
That's it now you have new attribute with name and code that you have enter in your file with all brands options that exists in magento.